# edit the only lines which matches some word

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have to search a file for lines with some specific words and edit these lines as follows. The other lines should remain the same.
For example:

```
    eltu r21, r24, r23
    brz r21, outer_end
    add r27, r0, r25
    jp outer_end
    add r27, r0, r22
   outer_end:
```

to be modified to:

```
    eltu r21, r24, r23
line2:  brz r21, $(outer_end-line2)
    add r27, r0, r25
line4:  jp $(outer_end-line4-4)
    add r27, r0, r22
outer_end:
```

Can any one please help how to use AWK to achieve this.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to figure it out for yourself. If you have a *specific* question, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [edi[t your question to tell us what these "specific words" are and explain the transformation from input to output plus include what you have tried so far.

Comment: **Not Clear Enough** to figure out what is your pattern and based on **what** these lines should be edited. Clarify your question please.

Comment: **OR** can you use **Perl**: `perl -lpe '!s/^ +(?=outer)//g && s/^ +/line$.:  /g if not $.%2' file`

Comment: Thank dear! I want to change the lables in jump and branch instructions and want to label all these instructions w.r.t their line number and also to modify the offset address in branch/jump instructions. I have tried the following AWK script but does not give me the required results.
 /brz/ {
        printf("br%d: $1\t$2\t$($3-br%d-4)\n", NR,NR);
}

Comment: /brz/ {
        printf("br%d: "$1"\t"$2"\t$("$3"-br%d-4)\n", NR,NR);
}
gave me the required result. But now all the un-matched lines are not returned. I want to modify the line if there is a match otherwise keep the line same.

When applied this AWK script on the above file, it returned:
br2: brz r21, $(outer_end-br2-4)

Comment: @Sajjad, where is the `awk` code you'd like help with? I'd be happy to help you, but I can't see where you're having trouble unless you include the code in your question. (Comments are a terrible place for questions due to lack of formatting. Put your question in the question.)

Comment: @Sajjad I suppose the `outer_end-line4-4` in line 4 should be `outer_end-line4`?

Comment: I can't believe this question has 3 answers. The right answer could be `42` for all the info in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/brz|jp/{ 
   last=$NF;
   NF--;
   printf("line%s:\t%s $(%s-line%s)\n", NR, $0, last, NR); next }
NF>1{ print $0; next }
{ print $1 }
```

**Explanation**:

When `brz` or `jp` matches, save last field in `last`, remove last field with `NF--` and print the resulting line.

If it is a line containing multiple fields `NF>1` then just print it.
Last possibility is a label line, only the first field needs to be printed.

**In action**:

```
awk -f tst.awk input.txt
    eltu r21, r24, r23
line2:  brz r21, $(outer_end-line2)
    add r27, r0, r25
line4:  jp $(outer_end-line4)
    add r27, r0, r22
outer_end:
```

Comment: You should mention that YMMV with `NF--`. It's undefined behavior per POSIX so some awks (e.g. GNU awk) will remove the last field as you want but others will ignore the instruction or could report an error (though I haven't see that last one personally yet).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those leading "*line#:*"s are illustrative of where the output should be rather than actual data, here's a two invocation `sed` method:

```
 sed '/brz\|jp/{=;s/[^ ]*$/\$\(&-line/}' input_file.asm | 
 sed -n '/^[0-9]$/{h;n;G;s/\n//;s/$/\)/};p'
```

Output:

```
    eltu r21, r24, r23
    brz r21, $(outer_end-line2)
    add r27, r0, r25
    jp $(outer_end-line4)
    add r27, r0, r22
   outer_end:
```

Note: `sed` is clumsy here, since `=` prints a line number *immediately* which is too early.  So a *2nd* `sed` is needed just to shuffle the line number where it belongs.